# Missing GCC 4.2 options in Project Info / Build tab in Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gcc

I have two very similar iPhone application projects open side by side, and in the Project Info Build tab of one, I have a bunch of GCC 4.2 option sections (in between Versioning and Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options) in one of the projects but not the other.

I have checked all of the settings that I can find to make sure that they match up and that the correct Base SDK is selected, but I cannot figure out why this would not be showing in one project and not the other.

Anyone have any suggestions on what to check for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diff the pbxproj files in a text editor. Can't remember what the mistake was exactly but it happened to me once and I was able to fix the project file by diffing with a known-good version.

Comment: Your idea to diff the pbxproj files led me to see some key differences  in the XCBuildConfiguration sections of the file with regards to the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY setting, so I went into the Build tab, switched the Code Signing Identity and the Any iOS entry below it to a different profile, and switched them back to iPhone Developer, and the GCC options magically appeared.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite right. It is not due to CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.
GCC 4.2 options appears after adding sources to "Groups & Files"->Target->"YourTargetName"->Compile Sources.
The rule is simple:
If "Target" has no sources yet, there is no GCC 4.2 options.